# How to display sqlite data in fragments..!

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-sqlite

I have activity that I can put 2 text in it and saved in DB
and I have 3 Tabs each one has different picture in it
Please someone can help me with the code that i can display those 2 texts on each tab! I don't know how I can make it!

SQLITE ACTIVITY:

[image: SQLITE ACTIVITY]

Tab1:

[image: Tab1]

```
public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "big.db";
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "images";
public static final String NAME = "name";
public static final String PLACE = "place";
public static final String KEY_ID = "id";


public DataBaseHelper(Context context) {

    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String CREATE_IMAGES_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE images ( " +
            "id" + "INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +

            "name TEXT, " +
            "place TEXT )";

    db.execSQL(CREATE_IMAGES_TABLE);
}


@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int i, int i1) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS images");
    this.onCreate(db);
}

public void insertentry(String name, String place) {

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(NAME, name);
    contentValues.put(PLACE, place);

    db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
}
```

}

```
public class Tab1 extends Fragment {
    DataBaseHelper db;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab1, container, false);

    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.img1);
    String photoPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Download/image1.jpg";
    Bitmap bitmap1 = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(photoPath);
    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inSampleSize = 8;
    final Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(photoPath, options);

    imageView.setImageBitmap(b);


    return v;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just use below code to retrive data from your table

```
class DbResponse{
public String name;
public String place;
}
```

now

```
public DbResponse getData(){
  DbResponse obj = new DbResponse();
  SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
  Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select * from " + TABLE_NAME, null);
  if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
  obj.name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(NAME));
  obj.place = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(PLACE));
  }
  cursor.close();
  return obj;
}
```

in your fragment class write

```
DataBaseHelper db = new DataBaseHelper(getActivity());
DbResponse response = db.getData();

textview.setText(response.name+" - "+response.place);
```

Hope it will help you out

Comment: thanks for answering quickly but i don't know how to write the code in the fragment  :( i have textView there and don't know how to pull from sql

Comment: hey I have changed my answer.

Comment: just create a object of your **DataBaseHelper** class inside fragment and using that object call its retrieve function (you have to make one inside this class) and inside that function write my above code.

Comment: should i put 
 SQLiteDatabase db = this.getreadableDatabase(); before Cursor ?

Comment: i putted db.getData();
        TextView a = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.txt3); in fragment class
the what must i do a.!!!!!! ?

Comment: Created like this
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

Comment: i wrote it but my main issue is what to write in the fragment class sry to be like this i'm new :(

Comment: you have to create one class named **DbResponse** to retrive two string from db and return it to fragment class.

Comment: i got red line under DbResponse response = db.getData();

Comment: have you changed your **getData** method inside db class?

Comment: It worked Thanks aloooooott..!
but why when i put new name and place at information class the text on the fragment dont change with it ?

Comment: because when you are saving new **name** and **place** in db, they are stored in table in next row position. So if you want to retrieve only latest values just drop the table using **dropTable** query before saving them into the database table.

Comment: how i can take just the last value ?

Comment: and sry still don't have the reputation to vote on answers

Comment: try to use **cursor.moveToLast();** instead of **cursor.moveToFirst();**

Comment: hey can u help me here too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39406081/how-to-display-every-tab-its-own-data-in-textview-from-sqlite

Comment: just want to know how i can put Name_Place id1 for tab 1
and Name_place id2 for tab2 
and if i wanted to change Name_Place to any tab it changes just for that tab that i want